# How can I store value in the array on the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My JavaScript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
    var photoList = [
        {"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},
        {"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},
        {"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},
        {"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},
        {"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < photoList.length; i++) { 
        if(photoList[i].name == photo.cover1 || photoList[i].name == photo.cover2) {
            console.log(photoList[i].id)
        }
    }
    // I want to store it in array like this = [3,5]
</script>
```

The result of `console.log(photoList[i].id)` is 3 and 5.

I want to store it in the an array like this : `[3,5]`. So if it meets the `if` condition, then the value is stored in the an array

How can I do it?

Comment: `result = photoList.filter(x => x.name === proto.cover1 || x.name === proto.cover2)`

Comment: Create an array variable and use `push` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array and push in it.Like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
    var photoList = [
        {"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},
        {"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},
        {"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},
        {"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},
        {"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}
    ];
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < photoList.length; i++) { 
        if(photoList[i].name == photo.cover1 || photoList[i].name == photo.cover2) {
            result.push(photoList[i].id);
        }
    }
    // I want to store it in array like this = [3,5]
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an array of the cover values and filter `photoList` and get only the `id` value of the objects.

```js
var photo = { cover1: "arsenal.jpg", cover2: "liverpool.jpg" },
    photoList = [{ id: 1, name: "chelsea.jpg" }, { id: 2, name: "mu.jpg" }, { id: 3, name: "arsenal.jpg" }, { id: 4, name: "city.jpg" }, { id: 5, name: "liverpool.jpg"}],
    covers = Object.values(photo),
    result = photoList
        .filter(({ name }) => covers.includes(name))
        .map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method and inside check values of other object using `some` method.

```js
var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
var photoList = [{"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},{"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},{"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},{"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},{"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}];

const result = photoList.reduce((r, {id, name}) => {
  const match = Object.values(photo).some(e => e == name)
  if(match) r.push(id);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with **Array**'s `map()` and `filter()`:

```js
var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
var photoList = [
    {"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},
    {"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},
    {"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},
    {"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},
    {"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}
];

var res = photoList.map(function(p){
  if(p.name === photo.cover1 || p.name === photo.cover2)
   return p.id;
}).filter(x => x);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the array before the loop, and then, from the `if` block, push the values you want to it.

Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
var photoList = [
    {"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},
    {"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},
    {"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},
    {"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},
    {"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}
];

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < photoList.length; i++) { 
    if(photoList[i].name == photo.cover1 || photoList[i].name == photo.cover2) {
        console.log(photoList[i].id);
        result.push(photoList[i].id);
    }
}
// I want to store it in array like this = [3,5]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) from array

```
var newarray = photoList.filter( (currentphoto) => {
    return currentphoto.name === photo.cover1 || currentphoto.name === photo.cover2;
})
```

that's enough

Answer (score 0):

You the reduce method more more detail http://underscorejs.org/#reduce.
And use some method.

```
var photo = {"cover1":"arsenal.jpg", "cover2":"liverpool.jpg"};
var photoList = [{"id":1, "name":"chelsea.jpg"},{"id":2, "name":"mu.jpg"},{"id":3, "name":"arsenal.jpg"},{"id":4, "name":"city.jpg"},{"id":5, "name":"liverpool.jpg"}];

const result = photoList.reduce((r, {id, name}) => {
  const match = Object.values(photo).some(e => e == name)
  if(match) r.push(id);
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```